# Cannot create EXTERNAL TABLE on Azure SQL Databse

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

Can you not create an External table on an Azure SQL Database with a format file?  I'm trying to create an external table to a table I dumped into blob storage.

From this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935021.aspx

```
-- Create a new external table  
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name. ] table_name   
    ( <column_definition> [ ,...n ] )  
    WITH (   
        LOCATION = 'folder_or_filepath',  
        DATA_SOURCE = external_data_source_name,  
        FILE_FORMAT = external_file_format_name  
        [ , <reject_options> [ ,...n ] ]  
    )  
[;]
```

Is the documentation incorrect or am I missing something?  I can't seem to create a FORMAT FILE and keep receiving

> "Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'." error.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [DelimitedText] 
WITH (
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT, 
    FORMAT_OPTIONS (
        FIELD_TERMINATOR = N'~¶~', 
        USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = False
    ), 
    DATA_COMPRESSION = N'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec')
GO
```

Comment: Did you try it on an Azure SQL Data Warehouse instead as my answer suggests? Please consider marking it the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is (probably) that you are trying to use [`PolyBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt143171.aspx) on an Azure SQL *Database*, but PolyBase is only supported on on SQL Service 2016 on-premise. It is, however, supported on Azure SQL *Datawarehouse*: [PolyBase Versioned Feature Summary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703314.aspx)

If you instead of an Azure SQL Database create an Azure SQL Datawarehouse you should have the PolyBase features available, including creating an external file format.

[image: SQL data warehouse in Azure portal]

Running this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT TextFormat 
WITH (
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT, 
    FORMAT_OPTIONS (
        FIELD_TERMINATOR = N'~¶~', 
        USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = False
    ), 
    DATA_COMPRESSION = N'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec')
GO
```

On an **Azure SQL Database** will give you an error like:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'.
```

Running the same thing on **Azure SQL Data warehouse** will work

```
Command(s) completed successfully.
```

You will not be able to work with Hadoop databases using Azure SQL data warehouse, but working with Azure blob Storage is supported.